# SDL multi threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, sdl, threadpool

I am trying to make a program in C++ that sorts 100 numbers or so with merge sort by using multi threading with SDL. first of all this is what my program errors when i first make the thread...

```
SDL_Thread *threadA = SDL_CreateThread(MergeSort, "B", (vector<int> *)NULL);
```

and this is the function prototype:

```
void MergeSort(vector<int> & A)
```

if i can get this or if anyone knows of any simple multi threading tutorials on SDL it would help, thanks

Comment: In future you should probably post what kind of error you are getting and any error message associated with it.

Comment: error C2664: 'SDL_CreateThread' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void (__cdecl *)(std::vector<_Ty> &)' to 'SDL_ThreadFunction'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type

Answer (score 2):

The function passed to `SDL_CreateThread` must have the prototype `int ()(void*)`. That is, a function taking a single `void*` parameter and returning an integer. See the documentation [here](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlcreatethread.html).